# Vue.js: Simple click function not firing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a very simple app:

```
<div id="show_vue">
    <page-change page="bio" @click="changeThePage"></page-change>
    <page-change page="health" @click="changeThePage"></page-change>
    <page-change page="finance" @click="changeThePage"></page-change>
    <page-change page="images" @click="changeThePage"></page-change>
</div>

Vue.component("page-change", {
    template: "<button class='btn btn-success'>Button</button>",
    props: ["page"]
})

var clients = new Vue({
    el: '#show_vue',
    data: {
        currentRoute: window.location.href
    },
    methods: {
        changeThePage: function() {
            console.log("this is working")
        }
    }
})
```

...but when I click the `<page-change></page-change>` button, nothing is logged to the console.  I know I'm missing something simple but I'm not getting any errors.

**How do I make my click fire `changeThePage`**

Answer (score 29, accepted):

When you do :

```
<page-change page="bio" @click="changeThePage"></page-change>
```

That means that your are waiting `page-change` component emit the `click` event.

### Best solution (thanks to @aeharding) : Use .native event modifier

```
<page-change page="bio" @click.native="changeThePage"></page-change>
```

### Solution 1 : emit click event from child component :

```
Vue.component("page-change", {
    template: "<button @click='clicked' class='btn btn-success'>Button</button>",
    props: ["page"],
    methods: {
       clicked: function(event) {
         this.$emit('click', this.page, event); 
       }
    }
})
```

For information `event` is the default value passed by Vue for native event like `click` : [DOM event](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Methods-in-Inline-Handlers)

### Solution 2 : emit directly from parent component :

```js
Vue.component("page-change", {
    template: "<button class='btn btn-success'>Button {{ page }}</button>",
    props: ["page"]
})

var clients = new Vue({
    el: '#show_vue',
    data: {
        currentRoute: window.location.href,
        pages: [
          'bio', 'health',
          'finance', 'images'
        ]
    },
    methods: {
        changeThePage: function(page, index) {
            console.log("this is working. Page:", page, '. Index:', index)
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.5/vue.js"></script>
<div id="show_vue">

  <span v-for="(page, index) in pages" :key="index+page"
        @click="changeThePage(page, index)">
  
    <page-change :page="page"></page-change>
    
  </span>

</div>
```

Comment: Is that th only way to fire the parent's `changeThePage` method?  I thought there was a more direct route

Comment: @JeremyThomas I updated my answer : now you have a solution without emit in the child component.

Comment: @SLYcee another alternative would be to pass the `changeThePage` method to the `page-change` component. But your first method is the typical approach.

Answer (score 7):

The best way to do this is to use the `.native` event modifier.

For example:

```
<my-custom-component @click.native="login()">
  Login
</my-custom-component>
```

Source: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for me. It used to work with `@click` on Chrome but not on Safari. Adding `@click.native` doesn't work on both. Any idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

apparently `v-on:click` seems to work better with the `.native` event modifier.

try `page="bio" v-on:click.native="changeThePage()"></page-change>`. It worked for me.